# In MVC, posting of form return empty model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following viewModel

```
 public class ExerciceViewModel
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Titre { get; set; }
        public int QuestionCourante { get; set; }
    }
```

the following view

```
@model MonEcoleVirtuelle.ViewModel.ExerciceViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("test", "exercice", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Model.Code <br />

    @Model.Titre<br />

    @Model.QuestionCourante<br />
    <br />
    <br />

    Model.Code = "Code Modifie";

    <input type="submit" value="Post Moi Ca!" name="fini" />

}
```

and the following controller methods

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(ViewModel.ExerciceViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Content(model.Code);
            }

            return View(model);
        }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var vm = new ViewModel.ExerciceViewModel { Code = "code1", Titre = "Mon titre", QuestionCourante = 1 };

    return View(vm);
}
```

When I submit the form, the model passed is empty, all properties are reset, not keeping the original values.  What am I missing.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, instead of `@Model.Code` which just display the values, you need some inputs.

So `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code)` for example

To manage a collection, you can do something like that :

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Collection.Count; i++) {
  Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Collection[i].Property)
}
```

Comment: works, thanks, now what if one of the property of my viewmodelClass is a collection of something, how do i pass it all back.. javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

You have not included any input fields in your view.

The `@Model.Code` etc only output the value of the field. To be able to post back elements they need to be form elements, like inputs.  Use something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Code)
```

to create input fields that can then be posted back.

For a more complete guide see MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596(v=vs.100).aspx